# InterfaceProviderSpec prevented connection from: content_utility to: content_browser Using selenium with robot framework

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, robotframework

I am writing test cases using robot framework. When I run the test cases I receive the following error:

```
    [14968:6776:0614/094817.542:ERROR:service_manager.cc(425)] 
    InterfaceProviderSpec prevented connection from: content_utility to: 
    content_browser
```

The error appears at random times when running the test cases, sometimes in the beginning of the test, and other times somewhere in the middle. The page does not contain any popups or anything else that should be preventing interaction with the page.

Please Advise

Comment: Please post the text version of your error. Links and images don't last forever...

Comment: apparently, the "content_utility" function can't connect. This isn't a robot framework problem per se. It's just that the system under test is refusing a connection. I doubt that's something we can help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when there is a popup, foresee survey or CAPTCHA that holds from interacting with the page.

Comment: The Page does not contain any of these. Do you know of anything else that could be causing this? @AnjuThomas